# JavaScript window.open not detecting C# WebBrowser.Document.Window.Name on another browser instance

Tags: javascript, c#, html, windows, winforms

I have an HTML with a Javascript code that tries to open a named window if not exists, creates a form, and than posts to that existing window, using its target attribute.

I have a C# Form, with 2 webbrowsers controls in it, side by side, and than I open this HTML in browser1, sets the browser2.Document.Window.Name = "janelaoperacao", the target of the HTML form, and try to post the HTML form, and it opens a new IE window, instead of showing the result in browser2 window.

When I set browser1.Document.Window.Name="janelaoperacao", the posted HTML form shows up normaly on the browser1 window;

So, my problem is browser1.Document is not viewing the browser2.Document named window, and is trying to open another IE window instead. Am I missing some directives, so they can expose to each other inside the same form?

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Teste Java Script Window.Open identificada</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var PostObj = (function () {

            var hiddenForm;
            var i;
            var createHiddenForm = function () {
                hiddenForm = document.createElement("form");
                hiddenForm["style"].visibility = "hidden";
                hiddenForm["method"] = "post";
                hiddenForm["target"] = "janelaoperacao";
                hiddenForm["action"] = sucesso.html;
                hiddenForm["name"] = "hiddenForm";
                hiddenForm["id"] = "hiddenForm";
                document.body.appendChild(hiddenForm);
            };

            this.submit = function (urlDestino) {
                createHiddenForm();
                document.getElementById("hiddenForm").submit();
            };

            return this;
        })();
        function abreJanelaIdentificada(){
                var f = window.open("", "janelaoperacao", "location=no");
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="idPaginaRealizaCopia">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            function fazTudo(){
                abreJanelaIdentificada();
                PostObj.submit("file:///D:/temp/sucesso.html?teste=2");
            }

          //]]>                                       
        </script>
    <form>
        <input type="button" name="botao" value="Abrir" onclick="fazTudo();" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the WebBrowser code that does not work (it opens a new IE window):

```
    //after creating the form and stuff -> no errors before navigate, nor NullExceptions
    browser1.Navigate("file:///D:/temp/teste.html");
    browser2.Document.Window.Name = "janelaoperacao";
```

But, if I replace browser2 for browser1, it show the success message in the browser1 window  (browser1.Document.Window.Name = "janelaoperacao")

Comment: I don't think that's possible, because each WebBrowserControl is a completely separate browser, so the code that runs in them do not have visibility into the other control.

Comment: I see. But I don't want then to see each others code. What I meant was, like IE, when you open a named window, and then try to open it again, with a form post, I does not open another instance, it uses the same. In some way, it can see that there is a IE process opened, with that window.name.